# Apache - virtual host is not going to the correct directory?

Tags: apache, centos, virtualhost, httpd.conf

When i do `httpd -S` i can see the Syntax OK

```
port 443 namevhost xyz.example.com 
         alias xyz.example.com
```

But when i visit to `https://xyz.example.com/ajax/query`
it goes to wrong directory instead of defined directory.

**EDIT:**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
  SSLCertificateFile /root/digicert/LIVE/xyz.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/digicert/LIVE/xyz.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /root/digicert/LIVE/xyz.ca

  DocumentRoot "/home/www/html/xyz/public"
  ServerName xyz.example.com
  ServerAlias xyz.example.com
   <Directory /home/www/html/xyz/public>
      #AddDefaultCharset utf-8
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      #AllowOverride FileInfo
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
  ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
  TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
  LogLevel warn


  <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Files>
  <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Directory>

  SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
           nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
           downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
            "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>

# cat .htaccess 

RewriteEngine On


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Can you show the config of `xyz.example.com`?

Comment: I think I need domains `.htaccess` too.

Comment: Please see bottom of the EDIT section.

Comment: why don't you show all the apachectl -S output, at least all the virtualhosts? If you have just one you should be landing in the only virtualhost, if you have more chances are you have two with the same servername and landing at the first match.